# An inequality with matrix ranks

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem:

> Prove that if the formula below makes sense, then
>   $$\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}
> \rank {AB} + \rank {BC}  \le \rank {ABC} + \rank B$$

I really don't know where to start. Can you give me a hint?